# reusable function to get elements of repeater by index

Tags: protractor

How to use a function in  Page Object file to give elements of particular index in repeater when pass index to the function.

```
this.IncList = element.all(by.repeater("incident in $ctrl.allIncidents"));
this.Inc2ndElement  = this.IncList.get(1);
```

How can I put it in a function so that every time I pass a Index value to function and element at that index will be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a complex scenario in which there are repeaters inside repeaters and hence I wanted to fetch element by index of parent and child repeaters, I could achive it by: 
Panel Property Page :

```
    this.getTimeLine = function(IncId,TimelineId){
    this.IncTimeLine = this.IncList.get(IncId).all(by.repeater("event in $ctrl.timeline.filterBy"));
    this.IncTopTimeLine = this.IncTimeLine.get(TimelineId);
    this.IncTopTimeLineTime = this.IncTopTimeLine.all(by.css('span.timeline__time'));
    return this.IncTopTimeLineTime;
};
```

Call Function:

```
var TimeLine = Panel.getTimeLine(IncId, TimelineId);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put it in function passing a parameter-

```
 this.IncList = element.all(by.repeater("incident in $ctrl.allIncidents"));
 this.Inc2ndElement  = function(i) {
 return this.IncList.get(i);
  };

 this.Inc2ndElement(2); // gets the element at index 2
```

Comment: Thanks @igniteram this helped.